# Select multiple change event with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, select

I ma trying to get selected values from select element with multiple attribute. jQuery would return an array, but javascript only retuerns single value if multiple are selected.

```js
var fruits = document.getElementById('fruits')

fruits.addEventListener('change', function() {

  var selected = fruits.value
  console.log(selected)

})
```

```html
<select multiple="true" id="fruits">
  <option value="apple">Apple</option>
  <option value="banana">Banana</option>
  <option value="mango">Mango</option>
  <option value="grape">Grape</option>
  <option value="watermelon">watermelon</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the [`selectedOptions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedOptions) you can access the currently selected elements

```js
var fruits = document.getElementById('fruits')

fruits.addEventListener('change', function() {

  var selected = Array.from(fruits.selectedOptions, option => option.value);
  //or var selected = Array.from(fruits.selectedOptions).map(option => option.value);
  console.log(selected)

})
```

```html
<select multiple="true" id="fruits">
  <option value="apple">Apple</option>
  <option value="banana">Banana</option>
  <option value="mango">Mango</option>
  <option value="grape">Grape</option>
  <option value="watermelon">watermelon</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest way would probably be to use the [selectedOptions property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedOptions)

```js
const fruits = document.getElementById('fruits');
const output = document.getElementById('selectedfruits');

fruits.addEventListener('change', () => {

  var selected = Array.from(fruits.selectedOptions).map(el => el.value);
  
  output.innerText = JSON.stringify(selected);

});
```

```html
<select multiple="true" id="fruits">
  <option value="apple">Apple</option>
  <option value="banana">Banana</option>
  <option value="mango">Mango</option>
  <option value="grape">Grape</option>
  <option value="watermelon">watermelon</option>
</select>

<output id="selectedfruits"></output>
```

Comment: or `[...fruits.selectedOptions)].map(...`